# Use node js domains in handler function

Tags: node.js, node.js-domains

I have https server written in express js. And I added domains to my server. App.js file:

```
var d = require('domain').create();

d.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error("Domain caught error: "+ error.stack);
});


d.run(function() {
    var express = require('express');
    var appServer = express();
    var https = require('https').createServer(options, appServer);

    https.listen(8000, function() {
        log.info('Server is listening on port ' + 8000);
    });

    appServer.use(appServer.router);
    var routes = require('./routes')(appServer); //my routes file
});
```

I have route handler functions in other files. How can I use domain created in my app.js file in my route files without exporting it from app.js file.

**Update:**

routes.js file:

```
var auth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.namespace('/login', function(){
    app.post('/user', auth.verifyUser);
    });
};
```

auth.js file:

```
exports.verifyUser = function(req,res) {
    //here I want to see my domain
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it when you `require` your routes:

```
var routes = require('./routes')(appServer, d);
```

Then within your `routes/index.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(app, domain) {

    // ...

};
```

**Update**

To update the answer based on the question update, here's a possible solution to include the `domain` within each route definition. There are a couple ways to do this (you could make each route a class, which would be instantiated and passed the `domain`, then have a function defined per route, for example). Because the intent is to keep these route definition signatures `function(req, res)` as you've defined above for `verifyUser`, we're going to need to pass the `domain` to this route prior to calling the function. Keeping this *very* simple, we can do just that with a `setDomain` function:

Same code in your main `index.js` when you `require` your routes:

```
var routes = require('./routes')(appServer, d);
```

In your `routes.js`, you can pass the `domain` to the routes via the `setDomain` function:

```
var auth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function(app, domain) {
    auth.setDomain(domain);
    app.namespace('/login', function() {
        app.post('/user', auth.verifyUser);
    });
};
```

Finally, in your `auth.js` file, you can get the domain, and have access to it within the scope of the file to use it in the `verifyUser` function:

```
var myDomain;

module.exports.setDomain = function(domain) {
    myDomain = domain;
};

module.exports.verifyUser = function(req, res) {
    res.send("myDomain: " + myDomain);
};
```

I'm not sure I really like this solution, but again, it's keeping the signature the same for `verifyUser`. Maybe you'll think of a better one, or want to refactor your code to better make use of this domain you're passing around within your code (maybe define it somewhere else and pull it from there wherever it's needed).

Comment: Ok, but in routes.js file I have other files required, how can I see domain there?

Comment: You would have to do the same thing, pass the `domain` as an argument when you make a call to the function.  Really you can either export something or pass it as an argument.  You've said you don't want to export, so you'd need to pass it in some way.

Comment: If you provide code sample for the routes I could provide an example on how to do this.  Unless you got it figured out :)

Comment: Ok, I provide it in question.